# interactive lua: command line arguments

Tags: command-line, lua, interactive

I wish to do

```
 lua prog.lua arg1 arg2
```

from the command line

Inside prog.lua, I want to say, for instance

```
print (arg1, arg2, '\n')
```

Lua doesn't seem to have argv[1] etc and the methods I've seen for dealing with command line arguments seem to be immature and / or cumbersome. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm curious what "immature/cumbersome" solutions you've seen to such a [straightforward problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=lua+command+line+arguments&btnI=1).

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/CommandLineModule seems cumbersome compared to a built in argc, argv; getopt (at C:/Program Files/Lua/5.1/docs/stdlib/getopt.html on my machine) is has TODO written all over it and the advertised example is blank. Thanks for the pointer to the manual for arg. Google didn't do for me what it did for you, I've been all over the place trying to find this out. It's one of the things about being a n00b (again) - the simplest things just don't seem to work :-(

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're missing the `arg` vector, which has the elements you want in `arg[1]`, `arg[2]`, and so on:

```
% lua -i -- /dev/null one two three
Lua 5.1.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(arg[2])
two
>
```

More info in the [Lua manual section on Lua standalone](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#6) (thanks Miles!).

Comment: You're absolutely right, I am! 

Whereabouts in the manual is that? I'm not finding my way round it very well ATM. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I tried `lua -i -- one two three` on lua 5.2.4 and got `cannot open one: No such file or directory`. That makes me think the `/dev/null` is required (per `[script [args]]` in the manual, not `[script] [args]`) --- am I understanding correctly?  If you don't object, I will update the answer to explain.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @cxw re: `/dev/null is required` You could put any lua script path there.  `/dev/null` just means there is no script to run before entering interactive mode.

Comment: @mrcalendar it's explained in "Lua standalone" section

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the `arg` table, `...` contains the arguments (arg[1] and up) used to invoke the script.

```
% lua -i -- /dev/null one two three
Lua 5.1.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(...)
one     two     three
```

Answer (score 5):

Lua stores arguments in a table. This table is the "arg" table. You can access the passed arguments inside using arg[1], arg[2], ...

arg[0] is the name of the lua program. arg[1] is the first argument passed, arg[2] is the second argument passed and so on...

Comment: How would one define their own table name instead of "arg"?

Answer (score 2):

If you run file.lua in cmd of freeswitch

```
freeswitch> luarun prog.lua arg1
```

You can use prog.lua:

```
#print(argv[1])
```

And run: `$lua prog.lua arg1` (run in script folder)
You can use prong.lua:

```
#print(arg[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For OP and future visitors,

The library of Lua doesn't contain `injecting a table 'args' into globals from command line switches`. The program built from `lua.c` does, however, it is near impossible to use. The reason it is impossible to use is that program does NOT like multiple switches.

This is one of the reasons why my REPL/code executor `LuaConsole` was built. It gives you the table `args` as well as sends a tuple to the root pcall function (your executing environment is really a top-level pcall with probably an error handler attached). So both `args[n]` and `local a = {...}; a[n] ...;` all work properly with as many switches as you want. For example, -e to execute code from cmd line, -l to specify libraries, etc. It supports anything lua51 and up.

If you are having troubles with the program in the library, I highly suggest you check out https://www.github.com/tilkinsc/LuaConsole as it will save you the headache of dealing with a broken-feeling program. There are also other alternatives out there such as for web, fengari.

Hope this helps you!