# How to pass aruments to a Lua function from command line?

Tags: command-line, lua, command-line-arguments

I have the following `test.lua` script:

```
print("before function")
function calc(n)
    print("in function")
    print(10*n)
end
```

I'm trying to execute it from the command line using `lua test.lua calc 10`, but the only output I get is:

```
before function
```

What should I do to get the following output:

```
before function
in function
100
```

Comment: Note that your function never runs at all. If you want lua to do stuff with the command line arguments, your code needs to read the arguments and work things out itself

Comment: Maybe related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945819/interactive-lua-command-line-arguments

Comment: @JDong, the solution there seems to work only in interactive mode.

Comment: @Eric, how do I do that?

Comment: Then is this what you are looking for: http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/LuaManual-6.html ?

Answer (score 1):

For the following code,

```
m = {}

print("before function")
function m.calc(n)
    print("in function")
    print(10*n)
end

m[arg[1]](arg[2])
```

the command `lua test.lua calc 10` would output:

```
before function
in function
100
```

Comment: Why complicate things with a table `m`?

Comment: @lhf, it couldn't get it to work otherwise (assuming I would have additional functions in the same file).

Comment: You can use `_G[ arg[1] ]( select(2, unpack(arg)) )` in that case without involving `m`. The `select` `unpack` stuff lets you supply an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: `_G[...](select(2,...))` :)

Comment: @moteus, could you please make this into a fully working example?

Comment: test.lua `function add(a,b) print(a+b) end _G[...](select(2,...))` invoke `test add 10 20`